# Powershell - how to stop XML auto-correcting html in a file?

Tags: html, xml, powershell

is there any way to stop Powershell from converting/reading html characters in a file?

If I just open and then save an xml file:

```
[xml]$xml = get-content "c:\file.xml"
$xml.save("c:\file.xml")
```

The following key gets changed

from:

```
<add key="TimeFormat" value="h:mm&#160;tt"/>
```

to:

```
<add key="TimeFormat" value="h:mm tt" />
```

The point is, I don't want it to change any text, I want the HTML entities to remain as they were originally.

Thanks

Comment: HTML & XML entities are the same. You're getting `&#160;` because that space is a non-breaking space character, not a simple space character (ASCII character 32) (FTR, I have worked with plenty of XML files with spaces in attribute values doing exactly what you're doing and not seen this behavior). Open the XML in a text editor that can show you the difference and you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

`&#160;` (`0xA0`) is the non-breaking space in ISO-8859-1, but is not a valid character in UTF-8.  One of two things could be happening:

1. Powershell is expecting (or your XML file claims to be) UTF-8, and Powershell is silently replacing the invalid character with a space.  If this is the case, it really should be complaining with an error message.
2. (more likely) The XML file has the correct header specifying ISO-8859-1, and Powershell is replacing the entity with the actual '0xA0' byte.  As far as the XML standard is concerned, this is a perfectly valid thing to do, and you'll have to look at Powershell's XML documentation to see if you can provide options to the XML serializer to prevent this conversion.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the XML file is headed: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> I didn't know it's not an UTF-8 compatible character.

Comment: I'm really surprised the XML processor didn't complain.  It should have, since it's been told the file is XML but it contains an invalid character.